# Кратные 3 или 5

Tags: python

Нужна сумма всех чисел, которые кратны 3 или 5, до A.

```
def solution(A):
    sum = 0;
    for i in range(2, A + 1):
        if((i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0)):
            sum += i;
    return sum;
```

Выводит неправильное число

Comment: Приведите пример числа A, ожидаемый вами результат и фактический результат, который выдаёт ваш код

Comment: Почему у вас цикл до A + 1?
Надо разобраться в условии задачи. До А включительно, или нет? Если не включительно, исправьте `for i in range(2, A):`

Comment: По-моему всё у вас правильно. Вот чуть более короткий вариант: `sum(x for x in range(A+1) if ~x%5*x%3)`

Comment: Если вспомнить школьный курс математики можно обойтись без цикла :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выводится все верно, вероятнее всего вы не правильно проверяете, например считая до 15 вы забываете что 15 есть как в первом так и во втором наборе, и складываете вначале все кратные 3, а затем все кратные 5, хотя ваш код (правильно) считает число 15 лишь 1 раз.

## Тест 1.

Wolfram Alpha запрос: `multiples of 3 or multiples of 5 between 0 and 20`
Результат: `{0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20}`
Сумма: **98**
Результат работы программы: **98**

## Тест 2.

Wolfram Alpha запрос: `multiples of 3 or multiples of 5 between 0 and 35`
Результат: `{0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35}`
Сумма: **293**
Результат работы программы: **293**

## Тест 3.

Wolfram Alpha запрос: `multiples of 3 or multiples of 5 between 0 and 50`
Результат: `{0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50}`
Сумма: **593**
Результат работы программы: **593**

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/279305)

Comment: Уважаемый, результат выполнения программы соответствует результату подстчета. Это именно ответ на вопрос. Я не прошу внести изменения или высказываю замечания, я говорю по факту. Человек возможно допустил ошибку при проверке. Программа написана корректно.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin исключены ошибки при проверке

Comment: Все данные которые я пытался вводить совпадают. Обновил пост.

Answer (score 3):

Дорогой wan140! Вам нужно чтобы при обнаружении получения ноля к **sum** прибавлялось 3/5 или чтобы прибавлялось число, в ходе деления которого получился ноль? Если вам нужен второй вариант, то ваш код работает правильно. Если же вам нужен первый вариант, то вот вам готовый код:

```
def solution(A):
    total = 0;
    for i in range(2, A + 1):
        if i % 3 == 0:
            total += 3
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            total += 5
    print(total)
```

P.S. "переменная" **sum** у меня подсвечивалась не как переменная, поменял название на **total**. И ещё, пожалуйста, пользуйтесь табуляциями, а не пробелами.

Comment: 1. Мне нужно, чтобы при обнаружении числа кратного 3 или 5, результат увеличивался на это число.
2. В чем причина провала теста?
3. Мне удобнее пользоваться пробелами.

Comment: 1. Код у вас уже есть. 2. Вашу проблему решил давно, точно не помню в чём проблема, не пользуюсь конструкциями со скобками, if-elif-else лучше, как по мне.А вообще, откройте ваш код и мой, попробуйте понять почему они работают по-разному. 3. Ваше право

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input("Верхний предел числового списка= ")

chisla = list(range(0, int(a)))

print(chisla)

result = []

for i in chisla:

    if ((i % 3) == 0 or (i % 5 == 0)):

        result.append(i)

print(result)

print("Сумма чисел меньше ",a ," ", "кратных 3 или 5 ","=" , sum(result))
```

Результат:

Длина 35.

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]

[0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35]
Сумма чисел меньше  36   кратных 3 или 5  = 293

Длина 100.

Верхний предел числового списка= 51

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]

[0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50]

Сумма чисел меньше  51   кратных 3 или 5  = 593

Comment: Убери скриншот и напиши код в тело ответа.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Понял. Спасибо) Я впервые тут.

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(number):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(2, number):
        if((i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0)):
            sum += i
    return sum
```

Вам просто не надо было плюсовать :)

Comment: А чем это отличается от кода ТСа, кроме того, что не включается само число?

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce

    def solution(number):
        if number > 0:
            multiples = [i for i in range(number) if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0)]
            return reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), multiples)
        else:
            return 0
```

если это на codewars то я вот таким образом выполнил, но лучшее решение вот это:

```
def solution(number):
  return sum([x for x in range(number) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0])
```